# Merge/ Collapse entire data frame into a single column in R

Tags: r, transformation

Input data frame can have varied number of columns.
Output data frame should have only a single column which is a concatenation of all available columns in input data frame.

Example: Input

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ a    ║ b    ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║blue  ║ 5636 ║
║red   ║  148 ║
║yellow║  101 ║
║green ║  959 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Desired Output

```
╔═══════════╗
║    a-b    ║
╠═══════════╣
║blue-5636  ║
║red-148    ║
║yellow-101 ║
║green-959  ║
╚═══════════╝
```

This example has 2 columns, that input data frame can have any number of columns,so the solution should not  require column names.

I tried using transform,but that requires to specify the columns.

```
outputDF=transform(inputDF,xyz=paste0(inputDF[,1],'-',inputDF[,2]))
```

Is there a way where I can collapse all input columns into a single column separated by a '-'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
 v1 <- do.call(paste, c(inputDF, list(sep='-')))
 v2 <- paste(names(inputDF), collapse='-')
 setNames(data.frame(v1),v2)
 #         a-b
 #1  blue-5636
 #2    red-148
 #3 yellow-101
 #4  green-959
```

Comment: @user3243478 Updated the post.  Perhaps this helps.